User was removed? What's this about?
I got an update "User was removed" on Chinese SE (https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/2260/user13107?tab=reputation) and gained +2 credits for that. What was that about?

I received a similar update from 29 April, with a loss of 20 rep points.  Puzzling!

What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?
Some user gave you rep (plus or minus), but their user account was removed, so the rep from their actions was also reversed. In your case, it might have been downvoting you (-2) or you downvoted them twice (-1 twice).
